# consuming asp.net web service with php

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

I need to create a php soapclient that will consume an asp.net web-service. I have read the manual pages but I admit that I am fairly new to PHP.
20 years of typed languages might have me stuck on stupid.

I haved tried soapvar, arrays, classes. They all generally end up with a "Call to a member function CreatePurchase() on a non-object in..."

The ASP.net code works fine and produces this when fished out with Fiddler.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><CreatePurchase xmlns="http://licensing.mancosoftware.com/webservices/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><axCustomer><Customer Name="Ron Howard" EMail="RH@Anysite.com" FirstName="Ron E" LastName="Howard" Salutation="Mr." Company="RHP" Address="1313 Mockingbird Rd." Address2="1" City="Los Angles" StateCode="CA" CountryISOCode="USA" PostCode="99999-9999" Phone="888.888.8888" Fax="888.888.8888" Comments="Now is time for all good men to come to the aid of their country" xmlns=""><Purchase LicenseID="0" PurchaseDate="9/23/2012" Income="0.00" Comments="AOTC"></Purchase></Customer></axCustomer></CreatePurchase></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

So what is CreatePurchase looking for in the parameter field that I am missing?

Regards,

PHP Version 5.3.21  Apache 2.2.22

Here is the WSDL:

```
http://www.mancosoftware.com/ActivationService/ActivationService.asmx?WSDL

<s:element name="CreatePurchase"><s:complexType><s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="axCustomer"><s:complexType><s:sequence><s:any/></s:sequence></s:complexType></s:element><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="returnFullSaleInfo" type="s:boolean"/></s:sequence></s:complexType></s:element>

<s:element name="CreatePurchaseResponse"><s:complexType><s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CreatePurchaseResult" type="s:boolean"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="aoUnlockKeyList" type="tns:ArrayOfString"/></s:sequence></s:complexType></s:element>

CreatePurchase { axCustomer axCustomer; boolean returnFullSaleInfo; }" [5]=>  string(36) "struct axCustomer {  any; }"

POST /ActivationService/ActivationService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mancosoftware.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://licensing.mancosoftware.com/webservices/CreatePurchase"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <CreatePurchase xmlns="http://licensing.mancosoftware.com/webservices/">
   <axCustomer>xml</axCustomer>
   <returnFullSaleInfo>boolean</returnFullSaleInfo>
  </CreatePurchase>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <CreatePurchaseResponse xmlns="http://licensing.mancosoftware.com/webservices/">
   <CreatePurchaseResult>boolean</CreatePurchaseResult>
   <aoUnlockKeyList>
    <string>string</string>
    <string>string</string>
   </aoUnlockKeyList>
 </CreatePurchaseResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$params['trace'] = true;
$soapURL = "http://www.mancosoftware.com/ActivationService/ActivationService.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($soapURL, $params);

$result = $client->Login(array(
    "asUserName" => "xxx",
    "asPassword" => "xxx"
));


$name = "Ron Howard";
$email = "rh@abc.com";
$firstname = "Ron";
$lastname = "Howard";
$salutation = "Mr.";
$company = "RHP";
$address = "1313 Mockingbird Lane";
$address2 = "";
$city = "LA";
$statecode = "CA";
$countryISOcode = "USA";
$postcode = "99999";
$phone = "8888888";
$fax = "8888888";
$comments = "test 1";
$purchasedate = date("m/d/Y");

$writer = new XMLWriter();

$writer->openMemory();
$writer->setIndent(4);
$writer->startElement('Customer');
$writer->writeAttribute('Name', $name);
$writer->writeAttribute('EMail', $email);
$writer->writeAttribute('FirstName', $firstname);
$writer->writeAttribute('LastName', $lastname);
$writer->writeAttribute('Salutation', $salutation);
$writer->writeAttribute('Company', $company);
$writer->writeAttribute('Address', $address);
$writer->writeAttribute('Address2', $address2);
$writer->writeAttribute('City', $city);
$writer->writeAttribute('StateCode', $statecode);
$writer->writeAttribute('CountryISOcode', $countryISOcode);
$writer->writeAttribute('PostCode', $postcode);
$writer->writeAttribute('Phone', $phone);
$writer->writeAttribute('Fax', $fax);
$writer->writeAttribute('Comments', $comments);

$writer->startElement('Purchase');

$writer->writeAttribute('LicenseID', '0');
$writer->writeAttribute('PurchaseDate', $purchasedate);
$writer->writeAttribute('Income', '0');
$writer->writeAttribute('Comments', 'Test');

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endElement();

$Customer1 = ($writer->outputMemory(True));

$result = $Client->CreatePurchase(this is where I break down and cry and beg for help)

$result1 = $client->Logout();

?>
```

Comment: You initialize `$client` but later on use it as `$Client`, with a capital `C`. That's probably your problem.

Comment: Did you call it like this `$client->CreatePurchase(array('axCustomer' => $xml, 'returnFullSaleInfo' => true)`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.$Customer1 = ($writer->outputMemory(True));

$result = $client->CreatePurchase(array('axCustomer' => $Customer1, 'returnFullSaleInfo' => true));